# How can I edit value of TextInput

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to write simple React Native Redux AddTask app. 
 I did add and delete part.
 I can't edit input value when i'm typing something it is adding new input
 which is empty, How can i fix that.
 Below I added add part and edit part(which isn't working) with reducers.

AddTask.js.

AddTask.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class AddTask extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  addTask = text => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASK", text });
    this.setState({ text: "" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginHorizontal: 20 }}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Enter New Task"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.addTask(this.state.text)}
          disabled={!this.state.text}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              height: 50,
              backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Ionicons
              name="md-add"
              size={30}
              style={{ color: "#de9595", padding: 10 }}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default connect()(AddTask);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

task.js

```
let nextId = 0;
const tasks = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TASK":
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: nextId++,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false,
          editing: false
        }
      ];

    case "TOGGLE_TASK":
      return state.map(task =>
        task.id === action.id ? { ...task, completed: !task.completed } : task
      );
      case "EDIT_TASK":
    let tasks = [...state];
    let indexOfUpdate = tasks.findIndex(task => {
      return task.id == action.task.id;
    });
    tasks[indexOfUpdate].text = action.task.text;
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        tasks: tasks
      }
    ];
    break;
    case "UPDATE":
      return state.map(task => {
        if (task.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...task,
            editing: !task.editing
          };
        } else return task;
      });
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default tasks;
```

TaskList.js

```
const TaskList = ({ tasks, toggleTask, editTask }) => (
  <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
    {tasks.map(task => (
      <Card>
        <View pointerEvents={task.completed ? "none" : "auto"}>
          <CardItem>
            <TextInput
              onChange={() => editTask(task)}
              value={task.text}
                 />
          </CardItem>
        </View>
      </Card>
    ))}
  </View>
);
export default TaskList;
```

visibleTasks.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TaskList from "../components/TaskList";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tasks: state.tasks
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleTask: id => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_TASK", id }),
    editTask: task => dispatch({ type: "EDIT_TASK", task })
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TaskList);
```

Comment: Could you also include the initial state of the reducer, please? I see some bugs in your code but I am not quite sure what the right solution should be. Would be nice if you could include more code, e.g. different code sections for different files.

Comment: @Andre I added it, can you check ?

Comment: Try to keep the reducer code together in your question :). The best way to get a good solution here is to just copy each file into its own code view. So the state is just an array which contains the tasks? Check out if my posted solution fixes the problem.

Comment: @Andre No it is the same result

Comment: Then I would like to ask you to copy all the code of the reducer file and components into your question, like I described above.

Comment: @Andre I did it, can you take a look?

Comment: Yeah. I found one more bug. Check out the documentation of TextInput: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6933. You can see that it will have a parameter that is the new text. I will include this into my solution.

Comment: Updated my solution :)

Comment: @Andre Im getting syntaxError,
It doesn't allow to write with this syntax. {taskId, newText }

`editTask: (taskId, newText) => dispatch({ type: "EDIT_TASK", {taskId, newText }})`

Comment: I am sorry. Updated the solution: `dispatch({ type: "EDIT_TASK", taskId, newText })`

Comment: @Andre Again the same,when i'm trying to edit field it is adding empty Inputs

Comment: I updated the return value of the edit_task case in the reducer. Could you `console.log(action) ` like that: `const tasks = (state = [], action) => { "console.log(action)` so we can see what the reducer receives?

Comment: @Andre it worked thanksss a lot...... Only one thing left, when i'm tyring to edit, it makes field empty, doesn't allow change on old version,

Comment: Nice! As you can see in the documentation that I linked in the solution, there are two different `onChange` functions for `TextInput`. Try out `onChangeText` as I updated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I see is that within your `TextInput` you pass the task.id to your editTask function.

```
 <TextInput
    onChange={() => editTask(task.id)}
    value={task.text}
    />
```

but within your propsDispatching, you define the editTask function to get the `text` of the task and not the `id` as a parameter:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  editTask: text => dispatch({ type: "EDIT_TASK", text })
});
```

This might not be the only error but as you want to update the text of an task and the tasks could have the same text, try this:

Pass the task id and the new text to the reducer. For that you could also use `onChangeText` instead. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input) example, or check out the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchange).

```
 <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => editTask(task.id, text)}
    value={task.text}
    />
```

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  editTask: (taskId, newText) => dispatch({ type: "EDIT_TASK", taskId, newText })
});
```

So you can also clean up the reducer code a bit:

```
    case "EDIT_TASK":
      let tasks = [...state];
      let indexOfUpdate = tasks.findIndex(task => {
        return task.id == action.taskId;
      });
      tasks[indexOfUpdate].text = action.newText;
      return tasks;
```